# How do you create a function to check the attribute of another field in a separate model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Trait(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    animal_types = models.ManyToManyField(AnimalType)
   # slots = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=4)
#slots is meant to hold a value that determines where it can be placed in animal model
#i.e. null means anywhere, "2" means only trait 2
    #def TraitPlace(self):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
#need to add animal details like age and gender to a separate model or integrate/hardcode into animal model as they're only 7 options
class ANIMAL(models.Model):
    animal_type = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    first_trait = models.ForeignKey(Trait, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
#first trait and animal required as animals always exist and have at least one trait
  #  second_trait= models.ForeignKey(Trait, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   # third_trait= models.ForeignKey(Trait, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've got an animal model which is used to create an animal with up to 3 traits, the problem is that some traits have specific placement restrictions, i.e. "lithe" can only be in position 3, and glistening can only be in positions 2 and 3. It was suggested to add an additional "slots" field under the trait model.

I understand logically how it's supposed to work out, but am struggling with implementation. I tried to look up documentation and use hasattr under my first_trait but that didn't work or I just didn't have placement correct. Essentially I'm trying to make it so that when the Animal model is called, and a person adds a second trait, for it to go check the "slots" attribute in the database to see if the position of the "trait" is valid. so if slots was "1,2" or "2,3", they would be limited to just being in first and second, and second and third positions, respectively. I spent many hours just trying to make this work and couldn't do it, hoping one of you internet legends can help me out or point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try adding a model class to validate the data before inserting/updating into Animals & Traits

```
class AnimalTraits(models.Model):
   trait_name = models.ForeignKey(Trait)
   animal_type = models.ForeignKey(ANIMAL)
   slots = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=4)
```

A sql query to figure out what slots are valid for some user inputted animal & trait would look something like this

```
SELECT at.slots from AnimalTrait at, ANIMAL a, Trait t 
WHERE at.animal_type = a.animal_type
AND at.trait_name = t.name
AND a.animal_type = `$user_input_animal_type`
AND t.name = `$user_input_trait`;
```

& you can add some business logic to determine if the user input slot is in that return value. The nice thing is this can also be used to determine if the trait is valid for the animal

Comment: I can sort of see what you mean, I'm an amateur and this is my first full-stack project though so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding. Where do people usually put sql queries? It might also be helpful to mention that the data is not ever going to need updating, the names of the animals and traits are meant to be preset.

Comment: > Where do people usually put sql queries?


This really depends on what programming language you're using. If you're using sql alchemy with django, something like this might do it

slots = db.session.query(AnimalTrait, ANIMAL, Trait)
                .filter(AnimalTrait.animal_type==ANIMAL.animal_type)
                .filter(AnimalTrait.trait_name==Trait.name)
                .filter(ANIMAL.animal_type == `input_animal_type`)
                .filter(Trait.name == `input_trait_name`)

Comment: Basically the problem you're trying to solve is a many to many relational mapping (many traits can belong to many animals & vice versa) so you need an intermediary table that records separate information for a given combination

Comment: Yeah it's almost a many to many to many field setup by the looks of it, because not only do I have the initial trait to animal type relation, within that i almost need an extra table but it doesn't seem that I can make the additional relation of trait-animaltype-specifictraitplacement with just regular fields. I'll have to play around with what you've given me. Thanks!